# Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem for second order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

How do I verify if [Cauchy-Lipschitz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) is valid for second order ODEs? 
For example:

$$\begin{cases}
x''-x'-2x=te^{-2t}\\
x(0)=5/16\\
x'(1)=0
\end {cases}$$

I know to do this in first order ODEs by checking if $f(x,t)$  is uniformly Lipschitz continuous (with partial derivatives) but no clue with high order.

Thanks.

Comment: Generally you would transform this into first order system of differential equation with $z_1 = x$ and $z_2 = x'$ and prove that the resulting function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is Lipschitz. Except this equation is linear, why do you need to use Picard? It seems like overkill, we already have existence and uniqueness for those.

Comment: Thanks.. unfortunately is an exercise taken from a past exam of my course..not my decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for using the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, you must convert a non first-order ODE to a first-order one. For example in here by defining $y=x'-2x$ we obtain $$y'+y=te^{-2t}$$

Comment: I'm still stuck.. it seems that $f(t,y)$ is $C^1$

Comment: Why $C^1$? Since $f(t,y)=te^{-2t}-y$, so it seems smooth.

Comment: still confused ..$\partial_tf(t,y)=e^{-2x}-2e^{-2x}x$ is continuous

Comment: That's right. Since $$\left|{\partial \over \partial t}f(t,y)\right|=\left|e^{-2t}-2te^{-2t}\right|\le 1$$ then $f(t,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous